# test function that returns ReactNode with Typescript and Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I am trying to test a function that returns a `React.ReactNode` type, something like this:

```
export const getComponent = (
  storeParams: StoreParams,
  routeItem: RouteItem,
  Component: React.FunctionComponent<{}> | React.ComponentClass<{}, any>
): React.ReactNode => {
  if (isUnauthorized()) {
    return <Error type="auth" />;
  } else if (needsRedirect()) {
    return <Redirect to="/privacy" />;
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Component />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

I am trying to write unit tests for it but I am not sure how I can confirm that the functions return the correct ReactNode.

This is an example of the test:

```
test('return component', () => {
  const component = routes.find((r) => r.id === 'product');

  if (component) {
    const result = getComponent(
      { authorised: true, privacyAccepted: false },
      component,
      component?.component
    );
    // how do I check the component is correct?
  }
});
```

I am not sure I can confirm the `result` is what I am expecting? For instance how do I check the  function return the `<Redirect />` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using [enzyme](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/) package.

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

interface StoreParams {}
interface RouteItem {}

function isUnauthorized() {
  return false;
}
function needsRedirect() {
  return true;
}

function Error({ type }) {
  return <div>{type}</div>;
}

export const getComponent = (
  storeParams: StoreParams,
  routeItem: RouteItem,
  Component: React.FunctionComponent<{}> | React.ComponentClass<{}, any>,
): React.ReactNode => {
  if (isUnauthorized()) {
    return <Error type="auth" />;
  } else if (needsRedirect()) {
    return <Redirect to="/privacy" />;
  }
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Component />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```js
import { getComponent } from '.';
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

describe('64039945', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const component = {
      component: () => <div></div>,
    };
    const result = getComponent({ authorised: true, privacyAccepted: false }, component, component.component);
    const wrapper = shallow(<div>{result}</div>);
    expect(wrapper.find(Redirect)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64039945/index.test.tsx
  64039945
    ✓ should pass (18ms)

-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File       |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files  |    72.73 |       50 |       75 |    72.73 |                   |
 index.tsx |    72.73 |       50 |       75 |    72.73 |          15,24,28 |
-----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.588s, estimated 10s
```

Comment: thanx, very neat and simple! Thank you very much